# Google analytics custom variables are not working when placed page view tracking in html file and variable tracking in javascript file

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have implemented google analytics for my site. The tracking code works fine when all code was in .js file. And .js file was included in  tags of my html page.

Now, i have separated(split) code into two parts. I put pageView tracking in  tag of my html file to capture accurate load time. Then i put custom variables and event tracking in my .js file.

The code looks like below

## In HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My web site</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

    </script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

In Scripts.js file:

```
if (_gaq) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Status, ErrorCode]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Visitor ID', varVistorID, 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Time Stamp', tStamp.toString(), 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Source', 'online', 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Problem: I am not all custom variables getting capture. Only 0.03% of total visits custom variables are captured. that means if have 35000 visits, only 12 visitor ids are captured, instead of capturing all 35000 visitor ids.

In Firefox, i can see following values sent to GA for each time i access my page, but i can few reported.

`utme   5(Success*None)
utme    8(Visitor ID*Time Stamp*Source)9(Ravi0408-1210-4aa3-816d-c722203b345c*Tue Apr 08 2014 12:10:48 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time'1*online)`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following line from your inline script:

```
gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

You have repeated it in your scripts.js file anyway.

You are using anonomised IDs for your visitors I trust?

Answer (score 0):

The trackPageview code is right.

### Custom Report to view Page-Level Custom Variable Values

To view *Page level custom variables*, you'll need to specify explicitly the **metric** and **dimensions**, which can be done via the **Custom Report** (click the Customization tab).

The default dashboard will not show *page level custom variable* values. Here's a screenshot of my custom report configuration for custom variable of slot 2:

[image: Page Level Custom Variable]